# Neo4j log rotation server stops responding

Tags: performance, logging, neo4j, freeze

I'm getting an issue on Neo4j 2.2 in which the counts rotation seems to be causing the server to stop responding to requests.  My graph has approximately 50M nodes and 100M relationships.  I've attached the relevant log.

Once the rotation occurs, the server will no longer handle any more requests and I can no longer navigate to the web management page.  What actually happens in the counts store rotation?

Eventually I have to restart the server.  This always results in a forced shutdown and then it takes a long time to restart because the log indicates: "Recovery required for log with version 1361"

Thank you.

[image]

[edit]

I've added more detail about the size of the various neo4j files, including log file sizes:

[image]

[edit 06-15-2015]

Attached is a recent jstack file that display the blocked threads.  Additionally, I've included a vmstat file.

[Jstack file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B15N2OKVN5McdnExWS0tcERkVnM/view?usp=sharing)
[VMStat file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B15N2OKVN5MccTNtR2k0RHlpZnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you add more details about your type of requests, concurrency, load, size of log-files, graph-structure etc? Also if you could send me your graph.db/messages.log to michael at neo4j.org would be very helpful

Comment: How long are you waiting, when the server is in this state? It's flushing changes to the store files, which can cause a lot of IO. Amazon EC2 instances with EBS volumes, for instance, don't have a lot of IOPS.

Comment: I waited approximately 30 minutes.  Seems like a very long time to not respond?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Michael, I've sent you my messages.log file.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your email, let's sort it out offline and report the solution afterwards here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that rotating the transaction log requires that all changes to the store files be forced to the storage device, before the old transaction log can be archived and a new one created. This store flushing  can take a lot of time.

The good news is that Neo4j 2.3 will fix this: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4756